# Bootstrap CSS inherit height from sibling div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a backend guy trying to do some minimum css and I am struggling with this problem, I have this html code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2 class="text-info">Price Table</h2>
        <select id="pricing-level">
            {% for in_pricing_level in pricing_levels %}
                <option value="{% url 'catalogue:table' product_type in_pricing_level.0 %}" {% if in_pricing_level.0 == pricing_level %}selected{% endif %}>{{ in_pricing_level.1 }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Problem:**
The dropdown box is wrapped to a new line, which results in
[image]

**What I have tried is put them in to 2 columns:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="border: 1px solid red;">
        <h2 class="text-info">Price Table</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="border: 1px solid red;">>
        <select id="pricing-level">
            {% for in_pricing_level in pricing_levels %}
                <option value="{% url 'catalogue:table' product_type in_pricing_level.0 %}" {% if in_pricing_level.0 == pricing_level %}selected{% endif %}>{{ in_pricing_level.1 }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this results in dropdown box having minimum height and cannot be vertically center aligned with "Price Table"

[image]

While I can manually put in some padding/margin, is there a builtin way(ie without js) to make the dropdown div inherit height from the "Price Table" div?

Comment: No, just a control which will trigger page reload vis onchange

Comment: are you sure that the enclosing div which sits on top of "Price table" and dropdown field doesn't have a width defined??

Comment: There is a bootstrap experiment that adds a class that will make columns equal heights. Note that this uses flexbox, which will not work in older browsers:
http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2 class="text-info" style="display:inline-block;">Price Table</h2>
        <select id="pricing-level" >
         {% for in_pricing_level in pricing_levels %}
                <option value="{% url 'catalogue:table' product_type in_pricing_level.0 %}" {% if in_pricing_level.0 == pricing_level %}selected{% endif %}>{{ in_pricing_level.1 }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the "Price Table" div and the dropdown menu in a .col and vertically align it using:

```
.retail-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```